# ipython easy_install/pip error

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, python, pip, easy-install

gcc is complaining with the following when trying to `sudo easy_install readline`:

```
Running readline-6.2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-JEUNX3/readline-6.2.4/egg-dist-tmp-_THoHR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Am I missing some RPM dependency for a happy build environment?

`Linux vbweb 3.2.22-35.60.amzn1.x86_64`

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Amazon provide a `readline` package?! I swear, the more I hear about Amazon's AMIs, the less I like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the *ncurses* development package: `yum install libncurses-dev`.